# Windows Media Player PlayStateChange

Tags: vb.net, media-player, subroutine, windows-media-player

I am using Visual Basic.net and the Windows Media Player control. Is it possible to determine the Object when the PlayStateChange event occurs.

Here is the sub:

```
PlayStateChange(NewState As Integer)
```

There is no Sender Object in the sub. Is it possible to get the Object by overriding the sub or by another way?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I used to use the control:

```
    Public WithEvents MediaPlayerObject As WindowsMediaPlayer = New WindowsMediaPlayer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a `Windows Media Player Control` and subscribed to the `PlayStateChange` Event using the **Form's Property Editor**, the generated EventHandler has a signature of:

```
Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(sender As System.Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange

End Sub
```

which is what you were expecting, how did you add your Control and the EventHandler?

---

It looks like you are importing the WindowsMediaPlayer Library directly. Try right clicking your toolbox and selecting **Choose Items** Go to the [COM tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby6tzh5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and select WindowsMediaPlayer. You can then drop it on your Form. This will also create the proper Wrapper for the ActiveX control.

Comment: I have updated the post. Is the AxWindowsMediaPlayer different than the WindowsMediaPlayer?

Comment: @user2023359 I went to the Toolbox and added the WindowsMediaPlayer to the available Controls, then dropped it on the Form, I let VB create a wrapper for the COM Control

Comment: I see no such control. What do I need to do to add this control?